# How can a question with no answers be considered highly active?

Tags: discussion

This question has no answers, but I am banned from answering bc it is supposedly highly active. How is that?

[Joining open source projects](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/155547/joining-open-source-projects)

Comment: This is something to ask on meta.

Comment: it has no answers **you can see**. One reason a question gets protected is that it attracts low quality answers, which are deleted. For more, wait until your question migrates to meta where you can get a complete answer.

Comment: Whats meta?     How do I post there?

Comment: That question attracted some spammy answers. They were deleted, which is why you cannot see then.

Comment: I had wondered why open source tends to be buggy, poorly thought out  rubbish, now starting to get a clearer picture, it's done by beginners trying to learn for free. I think I'll start counting open source contributions as a black mark against applicants.

Answer (score 2):

What you were seeing there is a **Protected Question**. [This meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-or-highly-active-question) describes what that means.

Questions can be automatically protected in the scenarios [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109116/what-causes-a-question-to-be-protected-by-the-community-user):

> ...protection only kicks in:
>
> - when [3 to 20 (depending on site) low reputation users answer a question in the span of 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228805/213575) or,
> - whenever [three low reputation users answers are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89971/213575) or,
> - **whenever [two spam answers are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302235/165773)**

The question attracted two spam answers which trigger **automatic protection**. Another user has since removed this protection.